# How to use electron-redux in electron and react app to share state in multiple react renderer processes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, electron, electron-react

I use electron and react to build desktop application, in the way electron-redux works you need to import the reducers in the main and in the renderer processes as well , in case of react you can not import files outside of `src` folder, and by putting the reducers inside the `src` folder and import it in the main process fails because electron uses ES5 importing syntax and react uses ES6, when electron import the reducers it seems to force the entire file to use ES5 syntax,

after making all import/export statements in the reducers file to use ES5, electron still complains and actually complains about syntax that used in other react files other than the reducers file !

Is there a solution for this , or there is another way to use redux in electron react application ?

Thanks

Comment: very interesting! can you share a minimal example of the situation?

Comment: you mean code example ?

Comment: yes, or a simple repository we can clone to reproduce the problem